# Counting emoji characters in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm created a form where users can submit text to a smart contract.
The text limit is 160 characters.

Some text characters / emojis are correctly counted more than once. In my form, Javascript counts this correctly.

For instance: 1️⃣is has three characters: The digit one: 1,  variation selector, a Combining Enclosing Keycap.

**But in Solidity, 1️⃣ is counted as 7.**

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract MyTextCounter {
    function count(string memory text) external pure returns (uint256 count) {
        return bytes(text).length;
        // 1️⃣ outputs 7
    }
    
    function echo(string calldata text) external pure returns (string calldata textReturn) {
        return string(text);
    }
}
```

How can something like this be accomplished in Solidity?

Answer (score 2):

> For instance: 1️⃣is has three characters: The digit one: 1, variation selector, a Combining Enclosing Keycap.

It does have 3 characters, but they take 7 bytes.

> But in Solidity, 1️⃣ is counted as 7.

You are treating the text as bytes, so it's correctly returning 7.

One option would be to count the number of bytes - instead of characters - in JS on your front end:

```
(new TextEncoder().encode('1️⃣')).length     // Returns 7
```

If that makes determining your 160 limit more complicated, you can look at how Twitter assigns "weight" to different types of characters, here -> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/counting-characters

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not have advanced unicode or string processing capabilities, so what you are asking "how" the answer is "in very difficult manner that would not make any sense."

I suggest leaving complex string processing outside the smart contracts.